# Have a select in a form type load With a class

Tags: php, forms, class, symfony

I have two classes. One class event and one Suite

In the form of event I want to have a select build from the content of the table suite. For example in suite (the table) I have more and less. I would like to see 'more' and 'less' in my select.

I tried to use an entity Field but it doesn't work, I always get the message

> "Neither the property "suite" nor one of the methods "getSuite()".... exist and have public access in class Suite.

So at the moment I have a relation OneToOne in the event class and my formtype is like this

`->add('Suite', 'entity', array('class'=> 'Suite','choice_label'=>'suite'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `class` option looks suspect - unless it resides in the same namespace as your formtype class, it needs to look something like this:

`->add('Suite','entity',array('class'=>'AppBundle:Suite','choice_label'=>'suite'));`

Now, assuming that this is not the cause of the error (and it sounds like it's not - which means you've created a rod for your back by not following conventions), then the error contains everything you need to know: you've neglected to create a getter for the `suite` property of your Suite Entity.  Could be something as simple as:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="suite")
 */
class Suite
{
    ....

    /**
     * @ORM\Column( type="string", length=32 )
     */
    protected $suite;

    ....

    public function getSuite()
    {
        return $this->suite;
    }
```

This can even be done automatically (IF you're following established conventions):

[Generating Getters and Setters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#generating-getters-and-setters)

Here are some docs:

[Databases and Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) and 
[entity Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

Let me know how you go.

Comment: yes it was the problem it doesn't generate the getSuite method. I just create it and the problem was solve. Now i have to work on my others prbs ! i love programming ^^